# DNA string into fragments

Tags: r, for-loop, bioinformatics, dna-sequence

```
set.seed(101) 
genome <- paste(sample(c("A", "C", "T", "G"), 1000, replace = TRUE), collapse = "")
```

I need to create fragments of 50 from the above sequence.
I tried to use for loop but am not able to figure it out.
Please help. I am new to R programming.

The genome is organized into 20 genes, each of length 50 bases. The first 50 bases in the genome correspond to gene one, the next 50 bases to gene two, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
 res1 <- strsplit(genome, '(?<=.{50})', perl=TRUE)[[1]]
 nchar(res1)
 #[1] 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50
```

Or using `stringi`

```
 library(stringi)
 res2 <- stri_extract_all_regex(genome, '.{1,50}')[[1]]
```